# Initialize Automapper from a (GAC) Class library

Tags: c#, dll, configuration, automapper, gac

I'm currently experimenting with AutoMapper ( latest .NET 3.5 version).
To make AutoMapper work, you have to provide it with configuration details on how to map from one object to another.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ContactDTO, Contact>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, ContactDTO>();
```

you should do this when an application, service, website starts. (using global.asax etc)

Problem is, I'm using Automapper in a GAC'd DLL to map LINQ2SQL objects to their BO counterpart.
In order to avoid having to specify the .CreateMap<> details all the time I want map 2 objects, where can I specify this configuration **once** if possible?

Comment: Why not use a static class in your GAC file with an `Initialize` method since `Mapper` is also static?  Just call it once when you start your app.

Comment: the problem is that i'm using this in a data access dll which is used by many different projects, so there's no real single entry point to the Mapper Initialization.

Comment: Unlike C++, static constructors run on demand not when assembly is loaded.  If there is a entry point to your library then create a static constructor on that type to initialize.  Otherwise you can try [hacks like this](http://einaregilsson.com/module-initializers-in-csharp/)

Comment: good advice. I created a static class which I call from my DataContext OnCreated() method.
The class contains an Initialize methods which contains the mapping + a bool which keeps track if the Mapper has been Initialized or not.
Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: Has anyone come up with a real solution to this yet?

Comment: There's so many ways to skin this cat, especially if you're using dependency injection and AoP.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution is in AutoMapper itself.

Use AutoMapper Profiles and register them at startup.

The example bellow doesn't even require an IOC container if your Profiles do not require any dependencies.

```
/// <summary>
///     Helper class for scanning assemblies and automatically adding AutoMapper.Profile
///     implementations to the AutoMapper Configuration.
/// </summary>
public static class AutoProfiler
{
    public static void RegisterReferencedProfiles()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain
            .GetReferencedTypes()
            .Where(type => type != typeof(Profile) 
              && typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(type) 
              && !type.IsAbstract)
            .ForEach(type => Mapper.Configuration.AddProfile(
              (Profile)Activator.CreateInstance(type)));
    }
}
```

And them just implement Profiles just like this example:

```
public class ContactMappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        this.CreateMap<Contact, ContactDTO>();
        this.CreateMap<ContactDTO, Contact>();
    }
}
```

But if your Profiles have dependencies that need to be resolved you could create an abstraction for AutoMapper and register all Profiles just before registering the abstraction - IObjectMapper - as a singleton like this:

```
public class AutoMapperModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Load(builder);

        // register all profiles in container
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain
            .GetReferencedTypes()
            .Where(type => type != typeof(Profile)
              && typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(type) 
              && !type.IsAbstract)
            .ForEach(type => builder
                .RegisterType(type)
                .As<Profile>()
                .PropertiesAutowired());

        // register mapper
        builder
            .Register(
                context =>
                {
                    // register all profiles in AutoMapper
                    context
                        .Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>()
                        .ForEach(Mapper.Configuration.AddProfile);
                    // register object mapper implementation
                    return new AutoMapperObjectMapper();
                })
            .As<IObjectMapper>()
            .SingleInstance()
            .AutoActivate();
    }
}
```

Since I abstract all my tech in the domain this seemed the best approach for me.

Now go and code dude, gooooo!

PS- the code could be using some helpers and extensions, but the core stuff it's there.